# Insert data using entity framework code first

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-3, orm, entity-framework-4.1, entity-framework-5

I'm trying to save the data using EF code first and ASP.NET MVC 3

My POCO class

```
public class UserAccount { 
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
   [Required(ErrorMessage="Username is required")]
    public string Username { get; set; }
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Password is required")]
    public string Password { get; set; }
    public string Department { get; set; }
    public string Category_ID { get; set; }


}
```

contex

```
public class OnlineTest : System.Data.Entity.DbContext {
    public DbSet<UserAccount> UserAccounts { get; set; }
    public OnlineTest()
        : base("OnlineTest")
    {

    }
}


public class OnlineTestInitializer : DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<OnlineTest> {
    protected override void Seed(OnlineTest context)
    {
        context.UserAccounts.Add(new UserAccount { Name = "Admin", Username = "admin", Password = "adminpass", Department="All", Category_ID = "1" });
        base.Seed(context);
        context.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

My Applicaiton start

```
protected void Application_Start() {
    Database.SetInitializer(new OnlineTestMVC.Models.OnlineTestInitializer());
    var contex = new OnlineTest();
    contex.Database.Initialize(true);
    AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();

    // Use LocalDB for Entity Framework by default
    Database.DefaultConnectionFactory = new SqlConnectionFactory(@"Data Source=(localdb)\v11.0; Integrated Security=True; MultipleActiveResultSets=True");

    RegisterGlobalFilters(GlobalFilters.Filters);
    RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
}
```

I can initialize the database with default seeding data. My problem is, I can't insert data using below code.

```
var User = new UserAccount { Name = "abc", Username = "abc123", Password = "passwrd", Department = "CS", Category_ID = "2" };


using (var db = new OnlineTest())
{
    db.UserAccounts.Add(User);
    db.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: What's the idea of setting DefaultConnectionFactory after initialization?

Comment: @GertArnold I'm a beginner in EF.I'm getting same result when setting DefaultConnectionFactory before initialization .

Comment: But why do you do it at all? It is in the config file and if you want to set it, it should be `LocalDbConnectionFactory`.

Comment: @GertArnold I did't get you. what should i do?

Comment: @GertArnold Yeah I got the solution. Its working fine when i'm removing DefaultConnecionFactory. Thank you.