# Add Record to Entities Modal bootstrap

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, twitter-bootstrap-3

Im sure this should be easy, but I have searched and searched again and there is no a begginers tuto for this. I already did this with jquery ui dialog, but then I found bootstraps includes dialogs too(Modal). So can some one please guide me with a tuto link or just posting a simple answer here.

What I want to do is to show a popup to add a record to my database. I got this code from [Bootstrap Page](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/) and it works, but I dont know how to add the record to my database when user clicks button, where is that event? or can I go to my controller after user clicks button?

```
<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
  Launch demo modal
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-    labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
  <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;    </button>
    <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
  </div>
  <div class="modal-body">
    ...
  </div>
  <div class="modal-footer">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
  </div>
</div><!-- /.modal-content -->
```

Comment: this question is very broad and stackoverflow is not a place where you'd wanna do training. if you have a detailed questions let us know. yet I will add some tutorial links for you.

Comment: Like you suggested, wire up the controller so that when the user clicks on Save Changes, you call that particular controller with the Model passed to it

Comment: @jose Ty jose I googled what you told me that seems to be the way, thanks and sorry for my no clear question

Answer (score 0):

1:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj592676.aspx

2:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj205424.aspx

3:
[Insert data using entity framework code first](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15726778/insert-data-using-entity-framework-code-first)

4:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-net-tutorials-entity-framework-winform-data-source.html

Comment: Thanks. I really have tried hard but have not found a nice tutorial. I really apreciate your help

Comment: I know how to use entities, the problem is how to control when user clicks on save